# Qt QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData() does not work

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5

Here is simple code:

```
QByteArray ba  = jdoc.toBinaryData();
QJsonDocument jdoc2;
jdoc2.fromBinaryData(ba);
qDebug() << jdoc.isNull();
qDebug() << jdoc2.isNull();
```

Result: `jdoc` is not null, but `jdoc2` is null. What am I doing wrong? It looks like `jdoc2.fromBinaryData(ba);` does not work at all.
I use Qt 5.5.0

Answer (score 5):

[QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#fromBinaryData) is a static method. You need to write:

```
jdoc2 = QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData( ba );
```

Answer (score 3):

`fromBinaryData` is a static function: your call does'nt affect `jdoc2`. Try the following instead:

```
QByteArray ba  = jdoc.toBinaryData();
QJsonDocument jdoc2 = QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData(ba);
```